# How to add a CDN to a Ghost blog?

Tags: configuration, cdn, ghost-blog

I want to add a CDN to one of my Ghost blogs and I was wondering how to tie it in. I have the pull zone and zone alias created, but I do not know how to tell Ghost to use the CDN for static files.

Of course I can edit my theme and hardcode cdn.mydomain.com, but what about the inline images in the posts?

Thanks!

Comment: We looked into this briefly for our site allghostthemes.com but ended up deciding to wait till Ghost apps come out.  We have hard coded our CDN in several places but inline images are pulled through the CDN.

Comment: "but inline images are pulled through the CDN" did you mean NOT pulled? As this is what I ended up doing: hardcoding cdn links to my site and the only thing not on cdn are the inline images.

Comment: Yeop you are correct...there should be a not in there.